# Div content is mapping different components

Tags: reactjs

I want to ask how could I implement in reactjs the next thing.

Imagine a page with 2 buttons and a div. When I press one button the content of the div would be a list of components mapped. When I press the other button the div content would be another list of components ( different component type as well ).

So more or less, the effect that results from this is a menu inside a page that loads different things in a div.

I am also willing to hear other options of implementing this, but mostly i'm here to ask you for a short example of how could I implement this thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Component1 = () =>{
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Component 1</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

const Component2 = () =>{
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Component 2</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState("COMPONENT_1");
  const renderComponent = () =>{
    switch(component){
      case "COMPONENT_1":
        return <Component1/>
      case "COMPONENT_2":
        return <Component2/>
      default:
        return <div/>
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {renderComponent()}
      </div>
      <button onClick={()=>setComponent("COMPONENT_1")}>Render component 1</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setComponent("COMPONENT_2")}>Render component 2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can replace Component1 and Component2 with whatever you want.

Or

You can use a library like React Router https://reactrouter.com/

let me know if there is anything else you want me to add.

Comment: Thank you a lot, actually i am using react router in my project , but didn't know how to use it in this case